# Display Error in Dialog using wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

I would like to display an error dialog for a wxpython app I have.  Currently I'm using the following code that I found from a blog post that I can't seem to get to work. I added some code which I know will throw a directory name error and the error will display in the IDE but not throw up an error dialog as I would like it to.

```
   try:
       app = wx.App(False) 
       frame = MyScriptApp(None, "Move Tool") 
       app.MainLoop()

   except:
       import sys, traceback
       xc = traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info())
```

Comment: Print it in a Message Box if you want it to appear in a 
 GUI https://wiki.wxpython.org/MessageBoxes

Comment: If you encounter an exception before starting the main loop the display error will never get displayed.

Answer (score 2):

If, as @SteveBarnes points out, your error is likely to occur before the main loop starts, use an external (to `wx`) message library, such as `notify2`.

```
import wx
import notify2
try:
    a=wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame(None)
    a.MainLoop()
except:
    notify2.init('MyFrame')
    err = notify2.Notification("MyFrame Error","MyFrame not found")
    err.set_timeout(5000)
    err.show()
```

Comment: Thanks @Rolf of Saxony.  Unfortunately it's looking like notify2 may not be compatible with Windows from what I've ready.  When I try to use import notify2 it gives me a no module named dbus error.  I searched this error and looks like people are saying it's only for Linux.  Have you got to work on windows, and if so, how did you get dbus installed?  Or are you aware of a windows alternative to notify2?

Comment: @wilbev I use Linux, take a look at https://github.com/jithurjacob/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications, best of luck!